# Jquery writing a plugin with 3rd party library i.e. autocomplete

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

Just wondering what the correct action is when creating a jquery plugin which consists of search tool which is a single input box on the users page and want to include another library like twitter typeahead.js for autocomplete.

In my .js file where the plugin is created, do I just include the contents of typeahead.js above my plugin js code or keep it as seperate files (but then this would mean the user needs to include more files to run my plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest to include it as seperate file because in future when you will need to update it you will be easy to do so.